# Cannot use setTimout doesn't work in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Can I not use `setTimeout()` in a bookmark?

This works:
javascript:
document.location="mysite.com";
alert("test");
void(s);

This does not:
javascript:
document.location="mysite.com";
var t=setTimeout(function () {
alert("test");
}, 10000);
void(s);

Why is this?

Comment: My guess would be that the bookmarklet creates its own JS sandbox and then reaps it before the timer finishes.

Comment: The following will works in Chrome for me: javascript: setTimeout(function(){alert('Hi');}, 10000); Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you change a page the entire javascript context is destroyed and recreated(This for security reasons and the fact that a context hell would be made)

```
document.location="mysite.com";
```

efectively changes the context of the page destroying any javascript reference left(in your case the timeout). The moment the new page has started loading your page has a new context.

for your timeout to work you would need a server that takes more than 10 seconds to respond(based on your second argument 10000 or to reduce the timeout to something like 10 ms).

```
document.location="mysite.com"; 
var t=setTimeout(function () { alert("test"); }, 10);
```

why would you need this?

Comment: Want to load jQuery, give it a chance to load, then do some stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarklets can do no more than what normal embedded script on a web page can do. If you can't do it with normal JavaScript, you can't do it with a bookmarklet.

In your example, if run as normal javascript embedded in the page, as soon as the page reloads the timeout would be gone, along with all other variables from that page. (Don't be mislead by the fact that JavaScript embedded in script tags will be re-run as the page is loaded. That would create a new timeout, but the previous one would be deleted.)

A more precise test would be to put your bookmarklet code into an a hyperlink on the page and click it (`<a href="javascript:...">test</a>`). That is exactly the same as clicking a bookmark containing the same code. What you cannot do with this, you cannot do with a bookmarklet.

SOLUTIONS TO YOUR PROBLEM:

Option 1: Bookmarklet creates an iframe inside the current page, and continuously reloads the desired page inside that iframe.

Option 2: Bookmarklet opens a small window and inject javascript into it which continuously reloads the `opener` window.

Comment: If the iframe is the same domain you can manipulate it. But you don't need to access the content of an iframe to change its location. Just change its `src` attribute.